# Trouble getting divs inline from within Drupal Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, drupal

Before I get started I would just like to say that I've tried to put in some due diligence in reading about the rules of placing divs inline. I understand the difference between float and display (inline, block, and inline-block). I have tried targeting to a great degree of specificity the divs containing the content I would like to have inline, but with no results. Either I am missing the class/id name that I should be targeting, or I am missing where the styling is being inherited from that is keeping me from getting my results. I am also not sure if it is a Drupal problem, though I don't believe it to be so. This is a views block, and I am using Nodequeue if that matters. Any help would be extremely appreciated!

```
<div id="block-views-front-listing-block" class="block block-views no-title" > 
    <div class="view view-front-listing view-id-front_listing view-display-id-block customize-front-l view-dom-id-c7e9bbbe5f8b7d663eb76fc6da64aa95">
        <div class="view-content">
            <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
                <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        
                    <div class="field-content">
                        <img typeof="foaf:Image" class="image-style-medium-large" src="http://mysite.dd:8083" />
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="views-field views-field-title">        
                    <span class="field-content"><a href="/content/image-1">Some Location 1</a></span>  
                </div>  
                <div class="views-field views-field-field-price">        
                    <div class="field-content">Cost Per Month</div>  
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even views-row-last">
                <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        
                    <div class="field-content">
                        <img typeof="foaf:Image" class="image-style-medium-large" src="http://http://mysite.dd:8083" width="380" height="231" alt="Image-2" />
                    </div>  
                </div>  
                <div class="views-field views-field-title">        
                    <span class="field-content"><a href="/content/image-2">Some other location</a></span>  
                </div>  
                <div class="views-field views-field-field-price">        
                    <div class="field-content">Cost Per Month</div>  
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you again, I am desperate at this point. I have spent two days on this, which I am not proud of.

My goal is to get the div containers classes "views-row-1" and "views-row-2" inline.

```
* All styling below is default css for this responsive site at screen pixel     sizes of 1025px and greater */
.container {width:100%;max-width:1140px}
#content-column,.content-column,div.sidebar {float: left; clear: none}
.two-sidebars .content-inner {margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 25%}
.sidebar-first .content-inner {margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 0}
.sidebar-second .content-inner {margin-right: 25%; margin-left: 0}
.region-sidebar-first {width: 25%; margin-left: -100%}
.region-sidebar-second {width: 25%; margin-left: -25%}
.at-panel .region {display:inline;float:left}
.two-brick > .panel-row {float:none}
.two-brick > .panel-row > .region,.two-50 > .region,.three-50-25-25 >   div.region-three-50-25-25-first,.three-25-50-25 > div.region-three-25-50-25- second,.three-25-25-50 > div.region-three-25-25-50-third,.five-5x20 > .row-1  div.region-five-first,.five-5x20 .row-1 div.region-five-second {width:50%}
.two-66-33 > .region-two-66-33-first,.two-33-66 > .region-two-33-66-second,.three-inset-right > .inset-wrapper > div.region-three-inset-right-middle,.three-inset-left > .inset-wrapper > div.region-three-inset-left-middle {width:66.666666%}
.two-66-33 > .region-two-66-33-second,.two-33-66 > .region-two-33-66-first,.three-inset-right > .inset-wrapper > div.region-three-inset-right-inset,.three-inset-left > .inset-wrapper > div.region-three-inset-left-inset,.three-3x33 > .region,.five-5x20 > .panel-row > .region {width:33.333333%}
.three-inset-right > .region-three-inset-right-sidebar,.three-inset-left >   .region-three-inset-left-sidebar,.three-50-25-25 > .region,.three-25-50-25 >   .region,.three-25-25-50 > .region {width:25%}
.three-inset-right > .inset-wrapper {width:75%;float:left}
.three-inset-right > .inset-wrapper > .region,.three-inset-left > .inset-wrapper > .region {width:100%}
.three-inset-left > .region-three-inset-left-sidebar,.three-inset-left >   .inset-wrapper,.three-inset-left > .inset-wrapper > .region-three-inset-left-middle {float:right}
.three-inset-left > .inset-wrapper {width:75%}
.six-6x16 > .panel-row {width:33.333333%;float:left}
.six-6x16 > .panel-row > .region,.five-5x20 > .panel-row {float:none;display:block;width:100%;clear:both}
.four-4x25 > .panel-row > .region,.four-4x25 > .panel-row {width:50%;float:left}
```

Edit:
After taking the advice of Joshua Whitley, I have been able to get everything inline, but that isn't exactly what I wanted.

```
#block-views-front-listing-block {
display:inline;
}
.customize-front-l .views-row-1 {
display:inline;
}
.customize-front-l .views-row-2 {
display:inline;
}
.customize-front-l .views-field {
display:inline;
}
.customize-front-l .field-content {
display:inline;
}
```

If I change any of these everything just basically goes back to the way it was all stacked up horizontally. I would like the location and price to be below the pictures without having to do css gymnastics. Any further tips would be very appreciated.

Comment: can u provide ur css plz

Comment: or a link to the web site so we can inspect the code

Comment: The site is not yet live, but I have added the relevant css. As you can see there isn't really anything targeting the area I am wanting to style. That is another thing that has me puzzled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is likely due to a misunderstanding of block-level vs. inline elements. Even if you target .views-row-1 and .views-row-2 and make them both inline with enough specificity (or even !important) to override every other style from your site, you have further block-level elements (more divs) inside them that will default to display:block, taking up 100% of the container width, causing .views-row-1 and .views-row-2 to expand to contain them.

First, you should change some of these elements to more semantically appropriate elements (p, span, etc.) and you may need to override their default behavior.

Check out http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/ for more information and examples of both types of elements.

Comment: I can't really edit the html directly as it is generated by Drupal and the installed modules. At least I'm not aware of how I would do that.

Comment: Then you'll have to target each of the divs below the ones you want to make inline and make them inline as well.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that right now and see if it helps. Its just annoying because I think I'm going to have to put a lot more time in moving each div within those two main div around later. Maybe my next question will be how to change the html markup in drupal pages.